# Initialize an array from XAML at runtime

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, xaml

I'd like to initialize an array from XAML in runtime, sort of like on Android.
I've tried doing it like this:

```
<ResourceDictionary
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:coll="clr-namespace:System.Collections;assembly=mscorlib">

<coll:ArrayList x:Key="Hello"></coll:ArrayList>
```

But when I try to load it from XAML like this

```
 new ResourceDictionary { Source = new Uri("Commands/MPC/resources.xaml", UriKind.Relative) }
```

I get an exception. Not sure if I'm doing that right.

Comment: give us the exception, what happens?

Comment: Just a generic exception. No description.

Comment: You might thing it's generic, *post it anyway!!*

Comment: Is the "Build Action" of the XAML resource dictionary set to "Page"?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use System.Collections.ArrayList in Silverlight, because Silverlight doesn't have it.  See the [MSDN documentation for the System.Collections namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

One thing you can do is create a subclass of System.Collections.Generic.List<T> that does nothing more than fill in a value for the generic type parameter:

```c#
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class MyList : List<object>
{
    // Class has empty body
}
```

Then you can use it in XAML:

```xml
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mycoll="clr-namespace:MyNamespace;assembly=MyAssembly">

    <mycoll:MyList x:Key="Hello"></mycoll:MyList>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

If you know you're only going to be using this class with objects of type `SomeType`, you can subclass `List<SomeType>` instead of `List<object>`.